# System boots with error in systemd-modules-load.service

Tags: redhat, systemd, kernel-modules, rhel9

During the boot of my homeserver (RHEL9), I noticed an error message regarding `systemd` and some kernel module.

I checked the following:

```
[root@homeserver ~]# systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service
× systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2024-01-04 19:17:22 CET; 15h ago
   Duration: 1.845s
       Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8)
             man:modules-load.d(5)
    Process: 631 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 631 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 9ms


[root@homeserver ~]# journalctl _PID=631
Jan 04 19:17:22 homeserver systemd-modules-load[631]: Failed to look up module alias 'fuse': Function not implemented


[root@homeserver modules-load.d]# pwd
/usr/lib/modules-load.d


[root@homeserver modules-load.d]# ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 5 May 12  2023 fuse-overlayfs.conf


[root@homeserver modules-load.d]# cat fuse-overlayfs.conf
fuse
```

I'm not sure what needs to be changed/loaded/renamed to get that service to run without any error.